# Copy Button Removing Non-Breaking Spaces

Tags: javascript, copy

I have the following piece of Javascript. As i'm not great at writing Javascript, would somebody able to help amend it so that it replaces any `&nbsp;` with a regular space (if this is even possible?).

Thanks

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var text = $(element).clone().find('script').remove().end().find('br').prepend('\n').end().text()
    element = $('<textarea>').appendTo('body').val(text).select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    element.remove()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert this line after var text;

```
text.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160), "g"), " ");
```

Comment: @need value of 'text'

Comment: This is a 7digit reference number that is copied (from webapp A) and pasted by the user (into webapp B). The issue I'm having is webapp A automatically inserts a '&nbsp;' before the 7digit reference.

Comment: give me an actual 7digit with '&nbsp'

Comment: For example, if the user copies the following reference 5927632 from webapp A and pastes it into webapp B, it's automatically pasting '&nbsp;5927632'. I just need this &nbsp to be replaced with a normal space. The reference number is a variable, so it can be any number.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer -

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
     var text = $(element).clone().find('script').remove().end().find('br').prepend('\n').end().text()
     text = text.replace("&nbsp;", " ");
     element = $('<textarea>').appendTo('body').val(text).select()
     document.execCommand('copy')
     element.remove()
 }
```

Comment: Please share var text value .

Comment: This is a 7digit reference number that is copied (from webapp A) and pasted by the user (into webapp B). The issue I'm having is webapp A automatically inserts a '&nbsp;' before the 7digit reference.

Comment: I have tried this and it's working , please share the exact value of text variable , so that I can test my answer on that variable.

Comment: For example, if the user copies the following reference 5927632 from webapp A and pastes it into webapp B, it's automatically pasting '&nbsp;5927632'. I just need this &nbsp to be replaced with a normal space. The reference number is a variable, so it can be any number.

Comment: I have changed it to this  ->  text = text.replace("&nbsp;", " ") . How it works is -  E.g. text =  '&nbsp;5927632';  text = text.replace("&nbsp;", " ") , then if you console.log('text:',text) , it will output "text:   5927632". Is this your desired output ?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working either. Another solution would be to perhaps force everything being copied into the clipboard as plain text. Is this possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159582/discussion-between-paras-wadhwa-and-head-bigg).